# tx fee exceeds the configured cap while deploying in contracts in private network in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, private-blockchain, warnings

While deploying my contracts over private network which is configured in `geth` I am getting the following warnings. It seems suspicious to me as if some intruder is trying to breach the network. I haven't carried out any transactions yet and just trying to deploy the contracts via `truffle`. It was working absolutely fine back in days.

What could be the possible reasons for this?

Is this some one trying to do something in my network?

Following is my geth start command with screenshot of warnings.

```
geth --snapshot=false --rpc.txfeecap "2"  --cache=4024 --identity "Node1" --http --http.port "8545"  --http.api "eth,net,web3,admin" --networkid 1338 --nat "any" --datadir <datadir_path> --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "<my_address>" --password "<dir_to_password_file>" --mine --nodiscover --miner.gaslimit "15000000" --miner.gastarget "15000000"
```

[image]